# Android: Programmatically change android:name attribute for Application and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Is it possible to programmatically change the `android:name` attribute in code for Application and BroadcastReceiver? I would like to change the name of my App icon and Widget names programmatically, in order to reuse our existing localization infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution might be to have a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject) that contains your base code and then your projects that use the library can then override your existing resources by simply having the same name.  Hopefully this will be helpful..